# Alphabet classification Using Computer Vision

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am a beginner to image processing. I am trying to detect `A,B,C,D,1,2` Using `computer vision`.
**How can I detect & classify this image without deep learning**.
The images are
[A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJXuB.png), [B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFNz0.png), [C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox44l.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKF6y.png)

My assumption if it can be solved by contour analysis. But have no idea how to do.
Any implementation idea or help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TA I see, I deleted the comment, thank you to clarify that!

Answer (score 3):

As all your letters and numbers always appear to completely white, I'd preprocess your images first with some simple thresholding at high intensity grayscale values:

```
src = cv.imread("A.png", 0)
ret,thresh = cv.threshold(src, 245, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
```

You will get something like this as a result:

[image]

After this there is a number of ways you could detect which number/letter is present on the image. You could use a available OCR package like [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) or manually implement [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html) for every available number/letter.